# How to consume records from Kinesis Data Streams using KCL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

I am trying to consume Kinesis data streams using Kinesis Client Library similar to https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-learning.
But in this example they scheduled the process. I want to consume records afferent without scheduler.

I don't want to use DynamoDB, cloudWatch. Expecting a simple consumer to consume records in stream

Is there any way to process records without scheduler using java

Answer (score 1):

KCL uses DynamoDB to manage shard leases and checkpoints - this functionality/dependency is critical to what KCL provides. If you do not want these, I'm not sure why you want to use KCL in the first place. You can either use Lambda to consume your stream, or invoke the APIs directly - there is some sample code here - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-sdk.html