# Using java to stream index into elastic-search from dynamodb using trigger

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am a novice on dynamodb and elasticsearch.

Need to stream indexes into elastic search from dynamodb table by trigger using Java i.e. whenever a new record is inserted in dynamodb table the same has to updated in the elastic-search.

Most of the examples available in web are either incomplete or implemented in python/nodejs. If there can be any explanation on how to achieve this in Java or any links/reference articles are also welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915663/how-to-consume-records-from-kinesis-data-streams-using-kcl Check this answer. Also, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-java.html - check this.

Comment: @AnshulSaraswatKaul this seems highly complex compared to the nodejs and python examples